# Visually Optimizing JavaScript Conditional Operators that are stringed together

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

In JavaScript let's say we have the following code

```
var test = 'd';
if (test != 'a' && test != 'b' && test != 'c')
  alert('were good to go');
```

This *if* seems rather lengthy to me.  I would love to write something like

```
if (test != ('a' && 'b' && 'c')
  alert('were good to go');
```

Sadly this doesn't work.  What is a more elegant way to write this?

Comment: Did you mean to use "&&"? In your example, you could simplify it to "if (true)", since test cannot be 'a', 'b', and 'c' at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant to use &&  it's been edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = 'd';
if (!/[abc]/.test(test))
  alert('were good to go');
```

Comment: Why not if(!/[abc]/.test(test))?  "test" should be more efficient here than "match".

Answer (score 2):

You can't get do that, but you can get fairly close like this:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(v) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == v) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (!['a', 'b', 'c'].contains('d')) {
    alert('good to go');
}
```

Most decent JS libs should contains lots of variations on list prototypes like this.

Comment: ...with the standard caveat that messing with the prototypes of builtins is a good way to confuse yourself horribly later.

Comment: Usually a matter of just understanding the language. If you've come fresh over from a statically typed language, with class based OO inheritance, then sure, this can be strange. But it's easy to change to a function approach instead. I think this is much cleaner however. It's how Javascript works.

Comment: There is no reason to fear modifying prototypes of built in objects.  The only exception is the Object prototype which causes issues for iterators.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Matthew Crumley that this is a logically invalid question, as-is. For fun I'm going to assume you meant to use && in your question...

```
var test = 'd';
({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}[ test ]) || alert("we're good to go");
```

or..

```
var test = 'd';
!(test in {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0}) && alert("we're good to go");
```

Comment: I vote for your solution. Mostly because you finally fixed the typo in the alert string.

Answer (score 0):

One little helper function will take you far...

```
// If you write this...
function set(){
    obj={}
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
        obj[arguments[i]]=1;  
    return obj
}

// Then you can do this!
if (! test in set('a','b','c')){
    //Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: I have some kind of irrational fear of the in operator, for some reason.

Comment: As Prestaul mentions above, anything attached to the Object prototype will show up in a for/in of anything else, so for/in, has a bit of a bad rep, and I usually only use it for debugging.